# Remotely controlled civilian passenger jets

Tags: military, passenger, airlines, remote-pilot

Remotely controlled aircraft have existed since at least the first "world war" (eg, The Aerial Target), so any sensible review would suggest that all civilian passenger fleets would have been equipped with such systems since their inception. Are civilian passenger jets equipped with systems that allow remote conscription and control by the US military? If so, how long have these systems existed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141681/discussion-on-question-by-fertilizerspike-remotely-controlled-civilian-passenger).

Answer (score 4):

No, civilian airplanes that are designed to be piloted don't have any facility for remote control, and remote-control drones don't have on-board pilot controls. The only exceptions to this are prototypes and one-off refits.

For instance, the Boeing 720 that was used to [test a fuel additive that was supposed to reduce the risk of a post-crash fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_Impact_Demonstration) had remote-control hardware added to it, but also carried a pilot during test runs. But the military had no involvement in this, the remote control was done by a NASA test pilot.

Another example is the [Wisk Air Taxi](https://wisk.aero/), a prototype for a proposed fully-autonomous aircraft. According to their proposal, if these aircraft enter service, Wisk would keep a staff of licensed pilots on hand at their office to take remote control if one of them experiences a situation that the automated flight software can't handle. Again, though, there's no military involvement at all, any remote flying would be done by a Wisk employee.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141680/discussion-on-answer-by-hiddenwindshield-remotely-controlled-civilian-passenger).

Comment: In some sense, all fly-by-wire aircraft are "remote controlled". The person with the controller just happens to sit inside the aircraft. There's even research going on to replace cabling with wireless transmission to reduce weight. Then the cockpit would literally become a wireless controller.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, why stop at fly-by-wire?  Why not consider hydraulically actuated surfaces as remote controlled?  Or pushrods, or cables...?  "Remote controlled" by definition means the controller is not inside the aircraft - I'd suggest we leave it at that, otherwise it just gets silly.